# How to change the color of the cardview on button click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cardview

I have a few buttons and I need to set the colour of the card view as per the button click.
Basically, I'm adding a theme to my post, so on the preview page, I need to allow the user to select the colour of their choice by clicking the button.

Screenshot:
[CardView Page with Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHhQr.jpg)

Button Code:

> ```
>                Padding(
>                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
>                         child: Row(
>                           children: [
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.yellow,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.orange,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.brown,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.blue,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.green,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                             Expanded(
>                               child: MaterialButton(
>                                 onPressed: () {},
>                                 color: Colors.black,
>                                 shape: CircleBorder(),
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           ],
>                         ),
>                       ),
> ```

Cardview Code:

> ```
>                 Card(
>                           child: Container(
>                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                                 color: Colors.blue,
>                                 border: Border.all(
>                                     color: MyColors.black, width: 1.5),
>                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
>                             child: Column(
>                               children: [
>                                 Row(
>                                   children: [
>                                     Padding(
>                                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
>                                       child: CircleAvatar(
>                                         backgroundImage:
>                                             CachedNetworkImageProvider(
>                                                 _profileurl),
>                                       ),
>                                     ),
>                                     Text(_username),
>                                   ],
>                                 ),
>                                 Padding(
>                                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
>                                   child: Obx(
>                                     () => Text(
>                                       pollDataController1.question.value,
>                                       style: TextType.boldHeading,
>                                     ),
>                                   ),
>                                 ),
>                                 Obx(
>                                   () => ClipRRect(
>                                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
>                                     child: Image.asset(
>                                       (pollImageController.imageDisplay.value),
>                                       width: 320,
>                                       height: 170,
>                                       fit: BoxFit.cover,
>                                     ),
>                                   ),
>                                 ),
>                                 Padding(
>                                   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
>                                       vertical: 10.0),
>                                   child: Column(
>                                     children: [
>                                       Column(
>                                         children: [
>                                           Row(
>                                             mainAxisAlignment:
>                                                 MainAxisAlignment.center,
>                                             children: [
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(
>                                                   pollDataController1
>                                                           .op1.value +
>                                                       "  ",
>                                                   style: TextStyle(
>                                                     color: MyColors.offBlack,
>                                                     fontSize: 16.0,
>                                                   ),
>                                                 ),
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(pollDataController1
>                                                     .op1Emoji.value),
>                                               ),
>                                               SizedBox(
>                                                 width: 25.0,
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(
>                                                   pollDataController1
>                                                           .op2.value +
>                                                       "  ",
>                                                   style: TextStyle(
>                                                     color: MyColors.offBlack,
>                                                     fontSize: 16.0,
>                                                   ),
>                                                 ),
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(pollDataController1
>                                                     .op2Emoji.value),
>                                               ),
>                                             ],
>                                           ),
>                                         ],
>                                       ),
>                                       SizedBox(height: 13.0),
>                                       Column(
>                                         children: [
>                                           Row(
>                                             mainAxisAlignment:
>                                                 MainAxisAlignment.center,
>                                             children: [
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(
>                                                   pollDataController1
>                                                           .op3.value +
>                                                       "  ",
>                                                   style: TextStyle(
>                                                     color: MyColors.offBlack,
>                                                     fontSize: 16.0,
>                                                   ),
>                                                 ),
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(pollDataController1
>                                                     .op3Emoji.value),
>                                               ),
>                                               SizedBox(
>                                                 width: 25.0,
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(
>                                                   pollDataController1
>                                                           .op4.value +
>                                                       "  ",
>                                                   style: TextStyle(
>                                                     color: MyColors.offBlack,
>                                                     fontSize: 16.0,
>                                                   ),
>                                                 ),
>                                               ),
>                                               Obx(
>                                                 () => Text(pollDataController1
>                                                     .op4Emoji.value),
>                                               ),
>                                             ],
>                                           ),
>                                         ],
>                                       ),
>                                     ],
>                                   ),
>                                 ),
>                               ],
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ),
> ```

Comment: I think you can declare a string for the theme color and assign the default color.Every time user press the button, update the string parameter according to the user input. Use this string for the background color in the Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable for color and a function to change the color on tapping each circle button.

So an example would be:

```
Color cardBackgroundColor = Colors.white;
  
void changeColor(Color changeToColor) {
        setState(() {
            cardBackgroundColor = changeToColor;
         });
  }
```

then in your button code use it like this:

```
Expanded(
         child: MaterialButton(
         onPressed: changeColor(Colors.yellow),
         color: Colors.yellow,
         shape: CircleBorder(),
         ),
      ),
```

and in the Cardview Code change it to:

```
Card(child: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: cardBackgroundColor,
                 border: Border.all(
                 color: MyColors.black, width: 1.5),
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
```

This would be the quickest way to do it, although it might not be the cleanest.